# How to check if a record with a composite primary key exists in a MySQL table using Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a model with two primary keys. How do I check if a record is exists using them both?

Answer (score 2):

Just search for both keys in your query

```
Model::where('primary_key_1', $primary_key_1)
      ->where('primary_key_2', $primary_key_2)
      ->findOrFail();
```

Comment: @Mahmoud Nassar - did that answer your question?